# Is there a closed-form expression for the first k terms in a binomial series?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, closed-form, binomial-theorem

This is kind of two questions in one.

Firstly, does the following expression have a closed form?

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}x^i$$
$$\text{(first $k$ terms in binomial series)}$$

where $k$ is some integer $0 < k < n$.

Secondly, this question got me thinking: is there a way to know if an expression does not have a closed form? If the above expression has no closed form, how would I know?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3365008/472818, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2222833/472818 (and I thought I saw a more recent one, but I can't find it).

Comment: @mr_e_man I guess the first link answers my question in its question; there exists no closed-form expression for the partial sum of binomial coefficients. This surprises me, honestly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The direct answer:** No, there exists no closed-form expression for the partial sum of binomial coefficients.

**The extended answer:** There does exist an expression that uses the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $_2F_1$, but it isn't considered closed-form (shorter version of *Claude Leibovici*'s answer):

$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}x^i = (1+x)^n - x^{k+1} \binom{n}{k+1} \, _2F_1(1,k-n+1;k+2;-x)$$

---

Thanks to *mr_e_man* who supplied me with these two links:

1. [Calculating partial sum of binomial coefficients fast](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3365008/calculating-partial-sum-of-binomial-coefficients-fast)
2. [Is there a simpler (preferably closed-form) way to compute this sum of binomial coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222833/is-there-a-simpler-preferably-closed-form-way-to-compute-this-sum-of-binomial)

Answer (score 1):

There is at least an expression.

Write
$$\sum_{i=0}^k \binom{n}{i}x^i=\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}x^i-\sum_{i=k+1}^n \binom{n}{i}x^i=(1+x)^n-\sum_{i=k+1}^n \binom{n}{i}x^i$$
$$\sum_{i=k+1}^n \binom{n}{i}x^i=x^{k+1} \binom{n}{k+1} \, _2F_1(1,k-n+1;k+2;-x)$$ where appears the [Gaussian hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Thank you! Does using the Gaussian hypergeometric function give us an approximation or an exact expression?

Comment: @SNN. It is exact.

Comment: I noticed a small error: in the first line, (1+n)^n should be (1+x)^n

Comment: @SNN Sorry for the typo !